# How to ensure filename is wrapped in double quotes when running files in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When I execute a Python file in VSCode, the path of the executed file is supposed to be between double quotes, but for me it's not. I am able to execute the file by manually inserting the double quotes into the command.

*(i think this could help: all this happened to me after i installed a c++ compiler [MSYS2])*.

### I've tried

- Opening a new VSCode window.
- Running other files.

Comment: how exactly are you running the program? what part of the VS Code interface are you using?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Any updates here?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the official expansion **Python** executing script, which will not appear the double quotes you said.

*https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial*

[image]

If you think it is a problem caused by extension, you can use the following methods to find extensions and disable.

*https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect*